# How do I log in using only my username and a password

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

How do I set up my profile on Stack Exchange so that I log in just with username and password?

Right now I login using Facebook.

I have set up an alternative desktop only for coding, but I absolutely DO NOT want to have in that account my Facebook or email accounts to avoid distractions.

Yet I need to use Stack Exchange (this is for coding, after all and I have questions). How do I log in, without using all the Facebook or [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) or other services. Something as simple as: username, password.

Comment: We don't offer "usernames" to login with, but you can follow the instructions in the answer to the duplicate question to add a Stack Exchange OpenID, so you can login with an email/password combination.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will need to learn how to set up an open id. Especially since I need to have it working on a system where I am not logged in anywhere else.

Comment: Nothing to learn. When logged out, click "sign up" in the top bar, then you can fill Display Name, Email, and Password, see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vlJyq.png). One step and you're done and you'll have a Stack Exchange OpenID account